# How to delete certain rows in R within dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

my dataframe is like this

```
class  subject  marks
1      bio      30
2      chem     40
3      bio      0
4      phy      60
5      maths    0
6      chem     0
```

I want to remove all rows from the column "marks" which have "0"

I am trying following code and its not working

```
 df %>% 
  filter(!str_detect(marks, '0'))
```

Comment: it says this Error in type(pattern) : argument "pattern" is missing, with no default

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to use `str_detect`, you should use the pattern `^0` like this:

```r
df <- read.table(text="class  subject  marks
1      bio      30
2      chem     40
3      bio      0
4      phy      60
5      maths    0
6      chem     0", header = TRUE)

library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
df %>%
  filter(!str_detect(marks, "^0"))
#>   class subject marks
#> 1     1     bio    30
#> 2     2    chem    40
#> 3     4     phy    60
```

<sup>Created on 2022-07-14 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score -1):

Using base r method

```
a = read.table(text='class  subject  marks
1      bio      30
2      chem     40
3      bio      0
4      phy      60
5      maths    0
6      chem     0',header=T)

a=a[!a$marks==0,]
```

output:

```
> a
  class subject marks
1     1     bio    30
2     2    chem    40
4     4     phy    60
```